# Wordpress query for IN operator with multiple AND in where clause

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a WordPress query for IN operator with multiple AND in where clause.

```
$query="SELECT  event FROM $wpdb->prifix.wp_rsvpmaker rsvp WHERE user_id IN ($format) AND event != %d
UNION ALL 
SELECT eventid
FROM $wpdb->prifix.wp_payment_event WHERE pay_user_id IN($format) AND eventid !=%d";

$value[]=$usersRegisteFrOtherEvents;
$value[]=$eventid;
$value[]=$usersRegisteFrOtherEvents;
$value[]=$eventid;

$eventIDs = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($query,$value),ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: what is the value of `$format` ?

Comment: $how_many = count($usersRegisteFrOtherEvents);
$placeholders = array_fill(0, $how_many, '%d');
$format = implode(', ', $placeholders);

Comment: `$format` string or integer?

Comment: echo `$query` run your query in phpmyadmin work or not

Comment: My query is working for single condition in where clause, its not working with multiple conditions in where clause

Comment: `eventid !=%d` what???, this `eventid !=%d` should be `eventid !='%d'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126104/discussion-between-yousuf-patel-and-devpro).

Comment: It would be useful to see what the echoed $query looks like

Comment: did u checked ?? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code, make sure that all placeholders are correct in your array while passing to the `prepare` statement:

```
 $how_many = count($usersRegisteFrOtherEvents);
 $placeholders = array_fill(0, $how_many, '%d');
 $format = implode(', ', $placeholders);
```